# How do i route and permit Airplay traffic from one network to another?

Tags: routing, vlan, firewall, multicast

I have a guest network and a corporate network. There is a firewall (Cisco ASA) and a router (3750G L3 switch) sitting between these networks. All of my Apple TVs are on the guest network side. My wireless controller handles all of the Bonjour proxy/gateway stuff and will advertise bonjour services (Airplay) on one vlan to another. However, i still have to allow and route Airplay traffic from one network to another.

What would this acl/policy/rule look like? I've found [this article from Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202944) and [this helpful article](https://techsupport.cambridgeaudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200535411-What-firewall-ports-need-to-be-open-to-use-AirPlay-) with just the ports for Airplay. Is it just a matter of specifying the ports and setting the src and dst with the correct info? Or is there more to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. :)

As long as Bonjour is being propagated across, then all you need to do is allow traffic on the respective ports for Airplay. You may want to further restrict by IP since they're standard ports, i.e. http, https, rtsp, DAAP, and MDNS.